# change video view whit firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, real-time

I have an application that's play a video whit a videoview. This application have a child event listener on a Firebase db. I want to change the video inside my videoview when I change the parameter on my db (from another application).
the code still work but I can't listen to the change of the parameter.
here is the code

```
public class activity_main extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    VideoView videoview;
    TextView tV;
    String path;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mDatabase.child("parametri").child("nowPlaying").setValue("video01");

        videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        tV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video01;
        videoview.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
        videoview.start();

        mDatabase.child("parametri").child("nowPlaying").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                tV.setText(value);
                Log.e("Valore attuale: " , value);

                switch (value) {
                    case "video01" :
                        tV.setText("Video01");
                        path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video01;
                        videoview.stopPlayback();
                        videoview.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
                        videoview.start();
                        break;
                    case "video02" :
                        tV.setText("Video02");
                        path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video02;
                        videoview.stopPlayback();
                        videoview.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
                        videoview.start();
                        break;
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
```

Here is my db
[image]

Here is my class for the parameter:

```
public class parametri {

    public String nowPlaying;

    public parametri () {

    }

    public parametri(String nowPlaying) {
        this.nowPlaying = nowPlaying;
    }

    public String getNowPlaying() {
        return nowPlaying;
    }

    public void setNowPlaying(String nowPlaying) {
        this.nowPlaying = nowPlaying;
    }
}
```

Every part of my app works but I can't change the video inside the videoview. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use addListenerForSingleValueEvent, use addValueEventListener instead.

You can found what difference here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write